# retrieve some text columns using c++ much slower than python

Tags: python, c++, regex, split

I want to read some big file contents and check some column then store some lines of file based on the column value the sample line:

```
7774777761 72288833         2015/03/20     23:59:37       26       26   38 
  99944524 09671017         2015/03/20     23:59:44       18        1    8
```

I did it in Python this way:

```
import sys
if __name__=="__main__":
    if (len(sys.argv)<4):
        sys.stderr.write('Usage: trk finame fout  column value \n ')
        sys.exit(1)
    finame=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
    result=open(sys.argv[2],'w')
    nos=open("nos.txt",'w')
    col=int(sys.argv[3])
    val=sys.argv[4]
    for l in finame:
        llist=l.split()
        try:
            if llist[col]==val:
                result.write(l)
        except:
            nos.write(l)
    result.close()
    nos.close()
```

and then tried to do it in C++ using regexp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ifstream fstr;
  ofstream ofstr;
  string istr,result;
  int col;
  string val;
  if(argc<5){
    cout<<"you must enter right arguments"<<endl;
    cout<<"colgrab inputfile outputfile desired_col desired_val"<<endl;
    cout<<"for example :"<<endl;
    cout<<"colgrab TrkTicket.txt INCOM_HWI.txt 6 1"<<endl;
  }else{
    fstr.open(argv[1]);
    ofstr.open(argv[2]);
    col=atoi(argv[3]);
    val=argv[4];
    if(!fstr)
    {
      cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
      exit( 1 );
    }

    if(!ofstr)
    {
      cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
      exit( 1 );
    }
  }

  while(getline(fstr,istr)){
    //  cout<<istr<<endl;
    try {
      regex re(R"XXX( *(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+/\d+/\d+) +(\d+:\d+:\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+).)XXX");
      std::smatch match;
      //cout<<istr<<endl;
      if (regex_search(istr, match, re) && match.size() > 1) {
        result = match.str(col);

        if(val==result){
          ofstr<<istr<<endl;
        }
        //cout<<result<<endl;
      } else {
        //result = std::string("No match found");
        //cout<<result<<endl;

      }
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
      // Syntax error in the regular expression
      //cerr<<"Syntax error in the regular expression "<<endl;
    }
  }


  return 0;
}
```

My purpose to doing this was speed. But the thing surprised me was that Python version did the job in less than 10 sec for a 270 Mb file, but C++ version could not finish the job on 10 min.

How can I fix c++ version to do the job in less time?

---

Python version python 3.2

C++    version GCC G++ 4.9.1

---

**Edit 1**

I tried all proposed ways and with MikeMB way they are almost even :

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream fstr;
    ofstream ofstr;
    string istr,result;
    int col;
    string val;
    if(argc<5){
        cout<<"you must enter right arguments"<<endl;
        cout<<"colgrab inputfile outputfile desired_col desired_val"<<endl;
        cout<<"for example :"<<endl;
        cout<<"colgrab TrkTicket.txt INCOM_HWI.txt 6 1"<<endl;
    }else{
    fstr.open(argv[1]);
    ofstr.open(argv[2]);
    col=atoi(argv[3]);
    val=argv[4];
    if(!fstr)
       {
          cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
          exit( 1 );
       }

    if(!ofstr)
       {
          cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
          exit( 1 );
       }
    }

while(getline(fstr,istr)){
        stringstream sstr(istr);
        int i = 0;
        while (sstr >> result) {
           if (i == col-1 && result == val) {
               ofstr << istr << "\n";
               break;
           }
           i++;
        }
 


    return 0;
}
```

is there a way to improve performance more?

Comment: Well, the regex matching is somewhat more complex than the `l.split()` you let python do, but I suspect that the main culprit is I/O. Replace the `endl` in `ofstr<<istr<<endl` with `'\n'` to avoid flushing all the time, does that change things?

Comment: First thing you can try is to move the `regex re(...);` part outside of the while loop. Also: did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: I tried both and the time came down to about 60 sec but still about 6 times of python version.very interesting that replacing endl with "\n" has that much effect and i did compile with o3 optimization

Comment: What if you get rid of regex entirely? For example by using `operator>>` from `ifstream`? Or by using `getline` and splitting it using `stringstream`? I strongly suspect that using regular expressions is the issue here.

Comment: can you explain more about each method?

Comment: I have added the answer to the second method. The first one does the same thing but without the `stringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to **Edit 1**:

- Add [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) as first line of `main()` for
  nice speed boost.
- You don't need to read a line and then convert it to `stringstream` -
  you can read values directly from `fstr` to avoid copying.
- To get your data in milliseconds you can use indexed data format, for example import your data to [SQLite database](http://www.sqlite.org/), index the columns and use database queries to extract it.

Comment: how can i read ifstream directly to stringstream line by line?

Comment: I mean you saied:                                                                                  "You don't need to read a line and then convert it to stringstream - you can read values directly from fstr to avoid copying."                                        how can i do this?

Comment: @pumper something like `vector<string> values(7); while (fstr.good()) { for (u_int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) { fstr>>values[i] } fstr.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); /* .... */ }`

Comment: hi using this method i get a time almost half stringstream.thanks i think i get what i want.thanks all

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the `regex` entirely, you can try this (only the while loop is modified):

```
while(getline(fstr,istr)){
    stringstream sstr(istr);
    string field[7];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        sstr >> field[i];

    // do whatever you want with read values
}
```

This should work assuming that each line you read has 7 columns and the values in the columns do not contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a regex is quite expensive as it involves constructing a state machine, so, as mentioned in the comments, you should move the regex construction out of the loop, so you have to pay that price only once.

However, for such a simple case you probably don't need a regex at all. I'm not sure whether this is actually faster, but you could try the following:

```
while (getline(fstr, istr)){        
    std::stringstream ss(istr);
    int i = 0;      
    while (ss >> result) {              
        if (i == col && result == val) {
            ofstr << istr << "\n";
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```